# Do a command on a file while condition is True

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
for %%a in (.\*.jpg) do @if %%~za gtr 245760 (
    :WhileD
          resize /overwrite /width:imagewidth-100 %%a %%~na.jpg
          if %%~za gtr 245760 goto WhileD
)
```

The Code above should check all images in a folder and if it is greater than 240KB, it resizes it till its size becomes less than 240KB, and then process to the next file,

But it is not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `goto` commands break for loops.  Use routines to contain `goto` sub-loops.

```
for %%a in (.\*.jpg) do @if %%~za gtr 245760 ( call :WhileD "%%~a" ) else echo add move command here.
exit /b 0

:WhileD <File>
resize /overwrite /width:imagewidth-100 %1 %~n1.jpg
if %~z1 gtr 245760 goto WhileD
exit /b 0
```

#### Update

- Added else condition.

Comment: **%%a** will not be visible inside `:WhileD` when a call is made using `call :WhileD`

Comment: is there any way to add an else command in line 1? for example: 
for %%a in (.\*.jpg) do @if %%~za gtr 245760 call :WhileD "%%~a" else Move it
 ;I tried it but it is not working :( I mean else will not work

Comment: Yes, an else command can work. You just have to place parentheses around the if part to provide the scope bounds. `for %%a in (.\*.jpg) do @if %%~za gtr 245760 ( call :WhileD "%%~a" ) else echo add move it command here`

Answer (score 2):

```
:WhileD
for %%a in (.\*.jpg) do if %%~za gtr 245760 (
          resize /overwrite /width:imagewidth-100 %%a %%~na.jpg
          goto WhileD
)
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: By having the goto in the for loop, the for command will start at the beginning of the file list each time.  Meaning a **lot** of extra processing if the folder has a large number of files.

Comment: @DavidRuhmann: certainly. I was aiming for simplicity. I'm not sure that the extra rescanning of the directory would add significantly to the overall execution time - and I'd prefer this method if the target drive was FAT rather than NTFS. On a FAT drive, I'd suggest a `for/f...dir` method in order to be sure that the entire directory is scanned once whereas `for %%x in filemask` isn't as reliable. This method, for the cost of rescanning the directory (which is actually reasonably fast) suits both NTFS and FAT. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
FOR %%A IN (*.jpg) DO CALL :CHECKFILE %%A %%~nA
EXIT /B 0

:CHECKFILE
FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%1') DO SET FSIZE=%%~zA
IF %FSIZE% LEQ 245760 EXIT /B 0
resize /overwrite /width:imagewidth-100 %1 %2.jpg
GOTO CHECKFILE
```

Comment: Note that the `for` command in `CHECKFILE` and the second parameter `%2` are not needed.  Numeric variables support [parameter extensions](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).

Comment: Thank you David, I was not aware of that before